# ASP MVC - how to secure posts inputs in my forum?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I wonder what is the best practice to safely get user inputs and render it in my forum? I am talking about rich textboxes, and html tags that users can use within posts.

Comment: There's a small section about this on the wikipedia page for XSS: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting#Safely_validating_untrusted_HTML_input

Comment: Yeas but it is small and completely unrelated to asp mvc. :-/

Comment: Why not use BBcode or markdown instead of actual HTML?

Comment: Even if i use BBCode, i still need to render it, so, what tags can i render safely?

Comment: Theres a list of common ones on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBCode. Support those. You're in control of the markup that is rendered then. You basically go `user input`->`html encoded user input`->`bbcode to html converter`->`render output`.